# A bug(?) with "::before" in CSS

Tags: html, css

I made some cool css on my site so I can see what is code and what is not.

Now I want that everytime there is a code block - the text "Code: " will be above the code block.

So I did this:

```
.code::before {
content: "Code: ";
}
```

Now the problem is that the text "Code: " is inside the code block, what can I do?
Thank you

Comment: I don't see any *bug* here. this is the expected behavior of CSS generated contents.

Comment: The selector `::before` and `::after` adds the content to the target tag.  If you want to add it before the tag, you'll have to use a script.

Comment: No more room to answer. However you might want to consider: http://jsbin.com/jupaz/1/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is working correctly; pseudo elements do not create line breaks. Here's a workaround:

```
.code {
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
.code::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1em;
    left: 0;
    content:"Code: ";
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vro5ojb9/

Comment: Thank you very much!
I made some changes to fit it in and it looks perfect

Comment: Yes, it says that I need to wait 2 minutes and then I will mark this as the answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

`.code::before` means a pseudo element inside `.code` as the first element before any other child elements.

It doesn't mean an element before `.code` in the document.

[CSS Selectors:](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#before-and-after)

> **5.12.3 The :before and :after pseudo-elements**
>
> The ':before' and ':after' pseudo-elements can be used to insert
>   generated content before or after an element's content.

Your code is doing exactly what it is defined to do, it's not a bug.

Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple jQuery that actually inserts a `<p>` tag before the instances, no need to offset positioning:

```
$(function() {
 $($('<p>').html('Code: ')).insertBefore('.code');
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p32ufmza/