# content before and after for links, make that unclickable

Tags: html, css

I've searched tirelessly for this and am very surprised to not find an answer.

Very simply question: I have a link being rolled out via WPress and I'd like to wrap some characters around it for emphasis, but I don't want those characters to be *part of the link*. Aka, for:

```
a:before {
  content: " - ";
}
```

it produces

```
<a href="X"> - link text</a>
```

when I want

```
 - <a href="X">link text</a>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067239/a-bug-with-before-in-css indicates you'll have to use a script to do this, as it's not possible with pure HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use a *positive/negative* `margin` and `pointer-events`

```css
a {
  margin-left: 1em;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a:before {
  content: '- ';
 margin-left:-0.75em;
 pointer-events:none
}
```

```html
<a href="X">link text</a>

<a href="X">Another link text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Content of ::before selector will always be part of the selected element.
::before My link

In your case '-' will be part the anchor tag with CSS ::before selector.

To avoid this specify anchor tag within p tag or span tag and use ::before selector for that p or span tag

Inspect element now shows 
::beforeMy link

Plunker for reference: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZWm7yeIKcxbtLl5iNcMr?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
span::before {
    content: "-";
}
```

My link

Answer (score -1):

Based on an answer given to [A bug(?) with "::before" in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067239/a-bug-with-before-in-css), it seems you will require a script to do this for you, as `:before` and `:after` apply specifically to the content of the given tag, not to the tags themselves.

http://jsfiddle.net/n4suh0se/1/

```
$(function() {
    $($('<a>').html(' - ')).insertBefore('a');
});
```

This will insert `-` prior to every `<a>` tag in your document.